# Codeigniter URL question

Tags: php, url, codeigniter

I've been working with the awesome Codeigniter framework for PHP for a while. Anyways, i've still got some questions.

It's easy to make an URL look like (domain.com/about) etc, but how can i make this combined with the news? something like domain.com/news/war/this_is_war etc? or maybe domain.com/war/123

Os there any good articles for this? Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

With CI, a `page` controller function `function1(param1, param2)` corresponds to the URL `domain.com/page/function1/param1/param2`, assuming you've configured .htaccess to get rid of the `index.php`

If you want specific url formats to load specific controllers/functions, you can configure your routing parameters in `config/routes.php` - [see this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this :

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/CodeIgniter-Getting-Parameters-From-GET-P151.html

I think it's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The URI Class in CodeIgniter is probably best for handling this.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

It allows you to dissect the URI the person has entered (or linked to). You can then load content based on these parameters.